# Set insets for all activities (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to understand how to create an edge-to-edge layout in android studio with java although I find that I am having to duplicate the ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetListener() for every activity. Is there a way of making sure this applies to all activities without duplicating code across each activity?

This is currently how I'm setting the insets:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set window to full screen
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(getWindow(), false);

        // Get view activity_main.xml from id
        View view = findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

        // Set Listener
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(view, (v, windowInsets) -> {
            Insets insets = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            mlp.leftMargin = insets.left;
            mlp.bottomMargin = insets.bottom;
            mlp.rightMargin = insets.right;
            v.setLayoutParams(mlp);
            return windowInsets;
        });
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in a utility method and call it from each activity that uses it:

```
public final class ActivityLayouts {

    private ActivityLayouts() {}

    public static void applyEdgeToEdge(ComponentActivity activity, int fittedViewId) {
        // Set window to full screen
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(activity.getWindow(), false);

        View view = activity.findViewById(fittedViewId);

        // Set Listener
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(view, (v, windowInsets) -> {
            Insets insets = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            mlp.leftMargin = insets.left;
            mlp.bottomMargin = insets.bottom;
            mlp.rightMargin = insets.right;
            v.setLayoutParams(mlp);
            return windowInsets;
        });
    }
```

Then in each activity, you call it:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActivityLayouts.applyEdgeToEdge(this, R.id.activity_main);
}
```

---

Some people might suggest creating a BaseActivity class that you extend to make your other classes. Here are some writings about why you might not want to use that strategy:

- [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)
- [Android Nightmares  | Base classes](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/android-nightmares-base-classes-ccf55dbd0604)
- [Say no to BaseActivity and BaseFragment](https://proandroiddev.com/say-no-to-baseactivity-and-basefragment-83b156ed8998)
- [BaseActivity and BaseFragment are monsters](https://proandroiddev.com/baseactivity-and-basefragment-are-monsters-5cda31639938)